# Settings for Gnome-Shell Window Focus + "It's all text" Firefox Extension + emacs

Tags: firefox, gnome, emacs

I have the following setup:

- Ubuntu 11.10
- gnome-shell
- emacs 23
- Firefox with "It's all text" extension

The purpose of the "It's all text" extension is so that I can edit firefox text fields in an external editor, such as emacs. In fact, I am writing this from emacs. This extension is activated by pressing C-c C-e in Firefox, which opens emacsclient with a tmp file linked to that text box.

My question is, how can I have the emacs window come to the foreground after C-c C-e is pressed? It seems to be the "selected" window (I'm not sure of the right terminology), but it does not bring itself to the foreground. How can I configure this behaviour to happen?

As a second question: I often have multiple emacs clients connected to a single emacs server. How can I control which emacs window receive's the "It's all text" temporary file? I usually have one maximized emacs window (A) on one workspace and a smaller emacs window (B) on a desktop that also as Firefox. I want to make sure that (B) is the one that gets sent to the foreground.

Thanks for the help!